# Membership card and image

Tags: fields

if I would insert the picture of the contact in the membership card template. How to do this? What is the name of this field?
Alberto

Comment: file is called image_URL

Comment: {image_URL} in a email doesn't work to output the personal image

Comment: I googled 'civicrm token image_url' and got this https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/contact-image-in-message-template and many similar Q+A so you may find what you need amongst them